# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to createcall adapter for retrofit2.Response Kotlin Retrofit App

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

[EDIT]

Estaba desarrollando una App enAndroid, en la que he intentado implementar una llamada a un endpoint de una api concreta, y lo he intentado hacer con la libreria de Retrofit.

El endpoint que estoy intentando consumir es el siguiente:

https://hello-world.innocv.com/api/User/

El tema, es que al hacer la llamada,al principio no me llegaba nada, y ahora tras hacer unas modificaciones recibo el siguiente error:

```
java.langIllegalException: UNable to create call Adapter for retrofit2.Response<java.util.List<>UserElement>> 

....
....
```

El fragment donde realizo la llamada es el siguiente:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var recycleAdapter: UserAdapter
    private var userElements = mutableListOf<UserElement>()
    private lateinit var userById: UserElement
    private lateinit var btnAdd: SearchView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

        var root: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)



        /*
        viewModel.users?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){

            //TODO:Update the View
        }
        */

        //Inicializo la vista y levanto el RecycleView.
        initView(root)
        initRecycle()

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }

    private fun initRecycle() {

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        recycleAdapter = UserAdapter(context, userElements)
        recyclerView.adapter = recycleAdapter

    }

    private fun initView(root: View) {
        //Set the visibility to invisible until, the user do the request.
        val progressBar = root?.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
        progressBar?.visibility ?: View.INVISIBLE

        //Inicializo el Search, y le agrego el listener.
        btnAdd = root.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd)

        btnAdd.setOnQueryTextListener(this)

        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycleview)

        //Cargo el Array con los Usuarios de la API
        loadAllUsers()



        val btnAdd= root?.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.btnAdd)
        btnAdd?.setOnClickListener() {
            progressBar?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            btnAdd?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            //TODO("Implementar llamada a la API con Retrofit")

            val args: String = btnAdd.query as String

                userById = searchUserById(args)
            if (userById!=null) {
                userElements.clear()
                userElements.add(userById)
                recycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
        //Si lo llamo aqui explota.
        //HttpUrl.parse("https://hello-world.innocv.com/api/User/")?.let { loadAllUsers(it) }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        //viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)


    }
    private fun getRetrofit():Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://hello-world.innocv.com/api/User/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    private fun searchUserById(uid:String): UserElement{
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call:Response<UserElement> = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getUsersById(
                uid
            )
            val user: UserElement? = call.body()

            activity?.runOnUiThread{
                if(call.isSuccessful){
                    user?.let { userElements.add(it) }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No se ha encontrado ningun usuario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
        //Retorno el unico usuario que deberia haber con el id seleccionado.
        return userElements[0]
    }


    private fun loadAllUsers(): List<UserElement>{
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            //TODO: Puede que tenga que añadirle '/id' a call

            val call:Response<List<UserElement>> = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getUsers(

            )
            val users: List<UserElement>? = call.body()

            activity?.runOnUiThread {

                if(call.isSuccessful){
                    //show RecycleView
                    val userscall: ArrayList<UserElement> = arrayListOf()
                        for (input: UserElement in users!!) {
                            userscall.add(input)
                        }
                    userElements.clear()
                    userElements.addAll(userscall)
                    recycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }else{
                    //Show error
                    showError()
                }
            }
        }
        return userElements
    }

    private fun showError() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Se ha producido un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {

        if(!query.isNullOrEmpty()){
            //Cargamos los usuarios que haya en la API
            HttpUrl.parse("https://hello-world.innocv.com/api/User/")?.let { loadAllUsers() }
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        return true

    }
}
```

Mi ApiService.kt, seria el siguiente:

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("/User/")
    fun getUsers():Response<List<UserElement>>
    @GET(value = "/User/" + "\$uid")
    fun getUsersById(uid: String):Response<UserElement>
}
```

Y finalmente el Adapter del RecycleView donde trato de pintar los datos sería el siguiente:

UserAdapter.kt

```
class UserAdapter(val context: Context?, var userList: List<UserElement>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_user_layout,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.txtName.text = userList.get(position).name
        holder.txtBirthday.text = userList.get(position).birthday
    }

    fun setUserListItems(userList: List<UserElement>){
        this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

        val txtName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.name)
        val txtBirthday: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.birthday)

    }
}
```

Con respecto a la clase que uso como data class es la siguiente:

```
data class UserElement(
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("birthday") var birthday: String,
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int)
```

Si pueden ayudar muchas gracias de ante mano, y reciban un saludo!

Comment: Échale un ojo a esto: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide?hl=es-419 te recomiendo que uses viewmodels para las consultas al repositorio persistido en la app, y que modularices las invocaciones de Retrofit con una interfaz y un servicio, en vez de hacer las invocaciones como las haces.

Comment: @Fran Cámara muchas gracias por tu comentario! Recien acabo de empezar a usar Retrofit, y llevaba unos meses enfocado en otras tenologías como React Native, asi que estoy un poco oxidado en Android.

Comment: Nada, hay manuales muy buenos con los que empezar, no se mucho de Kotlin, por eso no te puedo ayudar mejor, pero en developer.android tienes todo, para el lenguaje que quieras, por eso te lo he compartido! Igual te ayuda más que yo en este asunto.

Comment: Hola Manuel, lo primero que debes realizar es verificar el LogCat si se muestra algún error y agregarlo a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Buenas @Jorgesys . Actualmente ya he realizado algunos cambiso en el codigo, y el error que recibo lo adjunto en la edicion del mismo junto con los cambios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que el valor que colocas en la anotación `@GET` será añadido al final de la url definida como `baseUrl`. En tu código se ve que la "baseUrl" en realidad es un endpoint completo

```
baseUrl("https://hello-world.innocv.com/api/User/")
```

y luego repites el último segmento en cada anotación

```
@GET("/User/")
fun getUsers(): Response<List<UserElement>>
```

Es decir que tu función `getUsers()` está enviando la petición al endpoint `https://hello-world.innocv.com/api/User/User`.

Además del error anterior, la forma que usaste para interpolar la variable `uid` también es incorrecta. En lugar de esto `@GET(value = "/User/" + "\$uid")` debes rodear el parametro con llaves (`{}`) y luego agregarle la anotación `@Path` al parámetro de la función.

Corrigiendo los errores tu código debería quedar así

```
private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://hello-world.innocv.com/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

interface ApiService {
    @GET("User")
    fun getUsers(): Response<List<UserElement>>
    @GET("User/{uid}")
    fun getUsersById(@Path("uid")uid: String): Response<UserElement>
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, efectivamente estaba repitiendo el endopoint Users 2 vecces. Ya he implentado los cambios pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error...

Comment: Podrías mostrar más lineas del stack trace?